# Calling on a function keeps giving me a promise instead of an object

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm trying to call a function and for it to return me an object so that I can manipulate it.
I'm doing `console.log()` at the end to see whether I'm getting the object but not luck.

```
var SubjTweet = () => T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'banana since:2011-07-11', count: 1 }, function(err, data, response) {
    return data;
  });


console.log(SubjTweet());
```

I'm looking for an object I can manipulate.

Comment: You need to use the Promise returned by `SubjTweet`. You can either do this: `SubjTweet().then( obj => { console.log( obj ); } );` or this: `;(async _ => { const obj = await SubjTweet( ); console.log( obj ); }();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)